# Polyglossia doesn't work with the ltxdoc document class

Tags: xetex, errors, polyglossia, literate-programming

I have a package that uses the [`ltxdoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxdoc) document class and the [`docstrip`](http://ctan.org/pkg/docstrip) program for code and documentation generation. The package deals with some multilingual stuff and needs XeTeX (to be precise, [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) itself, but this should be irrelevant), so I process it with `xelatex`.

Now I wish to use the `polyglossia` package to typeset a piece of text in another language in the `.dtx` file. However, I get a bizarre error when I add a `\setdefaultlanguage` or a `\setotherlanguage` command to the document:

```
! Package doc Error: Character table corrupted.

See the doc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.26 %   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
```

I've reduced it to this testcase:

```
% \iffalse
\documentclass{ltxdoc}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
  \DocInput{test.dtx}
\end{document}
% \fi
%
% \CharacterTable
%  {Upper-case    \A\B\C\D\E\F\G\H\I\J\K\L\M\N\O\P\Q\R\S\T\U\V\W\X\Y\Z
%   Lower-case    \a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\j\k\l\m\n\o\p\q\r\s\t\u\v\w\x\y\z
%   Digits        \0\1\2\3\4\5\6\7\8\9
%   Exclamation   \!     Double quote  \"     Hash (number) \#
%   Dollar        \$     Percent       \%     Ampersand     \&
%   Acute accent  \'     Left paren    \(     Right paren   \)
%   Asterisk      \*     Plus          \+     Comma         \,
%   Minus         \-     Point         \.     Solidus       \/
%   Colon         \:     Semicolon     \;     Less than     \<
%   Equals        \=     Greater than  \>     Question mark \?
%   Commercial at \@     Left bracket  \[     Backslash     \\
%   Right bracket \]     Circumflex    \^     Underscore    \_
%   Grave accent  \`     Left brace    \{     Vertical bar  \|
%   Right brace   \}     Tilde         \~}
%
% Hello World!
%
% \StopEventually{}
% \Finale
\endinput
```

I've observed that once I place `\setdefaultlanguage` (a single line) in another file and `\usepackage` (but not `\input`!) it, then it works. I'm out of ideas. How could one fix the bug?

(I have TeX Live 2010 and the latest `polyglossia` version.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The language definition files change the catcode of @ to 11, but never restore the original catcode. This is a severe bug that may cause much more trouble. Please report. Minimal example to reproduce:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\the\catcode`@ % should print 12, but prints 11
\end{document}
```

Until the bug is fixed, add `\makeatother` directly after the `\setmainlanguage` command.

(BTW, I wouldn't have thought that the character table check could be useful one day!)

**EDIT:** Reported at https://github.com/fc7/polyglossia/issues/#issue/13

**EDIT 2:** Fixed.