# Should a \CharacterTable still be used in dtx files?

Tags: documentation

My understanding of the use of a `\CharacterTable` in `.dtx` files is that it provides a visual check that the file was transmitted properly and there were no issues with character encodings.

Is it still necessary? I notice quite a few class and package authors include it after the `\endinput` line in order to minimize the visual clutter at the beginning of the file. Is this considered good practice?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Today files are typically distributed over HTTP and FTP, not e-mail or similar services that have to encode and decode binary (or even text) data. So, character translation failure is much less likely, and `\CharacterTable` could safely be omitted in modern packages. However, it does occasionally [catch random errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9638/polyglossia-doesnt-work-with-the-ltxdoc-document-class).

You shouldn't put it after `\endinput`, because it is intended to be processed by `doc` (which compares the table to a valid one), not just visually examined by the reader.

Additional note: some people prefer not to put the table in the generated file (because it is almost of no use there), and thus don't prefix the table lines with `%%`, but with a mere `%`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a good look at the link you provided and although it proved useful in the question that you linked, it actually caught a `bad practice` (by polyglossia) rather than a corrupted character. In the `doc` manual it describes a macro `CharTableChanges` that one needs to set up if there are any catcodes that deviate from normal TeX catcodes.  In the memoir class the `\CharacterTable` is after the `input` and that prompted my question. I was puzzled because I have such a big respect for Peter Wilson in anything TeX related.